# Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime in Persian calender

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I used the following code in order to present today's Persian date... the site I worked on have been online since two month ago and it have worked fine but today I received the following error:

Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

and I have no idea why this happened...is there any way to fix this?

```
protected void lbnChangeDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int year = p.GetYear(date);
    int month = p.GetMonth(date);
    int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    MultiView6.SetActiveView(View12);
    txtDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(d1.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

}
```

Comment: It means you're trying to create illegal `DateTime` with unexisting, impossible date. Debug and check year/month/day parameters.

Comment: Why no directly `txtDate.Text = d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`? My guess is that `Parse(..)` fails, while you don't even need it.

Comment: I did the debugging and today's date in Persian date is 1393/2/29...

Comment: `1393` is not a `Leap Year`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s don't remember how they were created. So, e.g. `d1` doesn't remember that, at some point in the past, you used a [`PersianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to obtain 3 `int`s and then use those in its constructor. That [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (implicitly) assumed that you were passing years, months and days from the Gregorian calendar.

Then, further, `DateTime.Parse` has no knowledge that long ago you accessed a `PersianCalendar` and did inappropriate things with it.

If you want to show the Persian calendar date as a string, just use it as:

```
protected void lbnChangeDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    txtDate.Text = string.Format("{0:0000}/{1:00}/{2:00}",
                    p.GetYear(date),
                    p.GetMonth(date),
                    p.GetDayOfMonth(date));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer works great...now I want to change the Persian date which is given in the txtDate.Text back to regular date to save it in the database.for example I want to change 1393/05/05 to 2014/05/26 then save it to database...
I used the following code however I encountered the same problem discussed in the first post...

```
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
                    string change = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    int day1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(8, 2));
                    int mon1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(5, 2));
                    int year1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(0, 4));
                    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
                    change = (pc.ToDateTime(year1, mon1, day1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Substring(0, 10));
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(change);
```

is there a way to fix this too?

Answer (score 1):

The exception error occurs at this code snippet :

```
System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
```

Which called in:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day)
{
  this.dateData = (ulong) DateTime.DateToTicks(year, month, day);
}
```

When step through that code it's like this:

```
private static long DateToTicks(int year, int month, int day)
{
  if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && (month >= 1 && month <= 12))
  {
    int[] numArray = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? DateTime.DaysToMonth366 : DateTime.DaysToMonth365;
    if (day >= 1 && day <= numArray[month] - numArray[month - 1])
    {
      int num = year - 1;
      return (long) (num * 365 + num / 4 - num / 100 + num / 400 + numArray[month - 1] + day - 1) * 864000000000L;
    }
  }
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException((string) null, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_BadYearMonthDay"));
}
```

The only way that method throws the exception is when the year is less than 1 or greater than 9999 and the month is not between 1 and 12. So I suggest you making sure you are passing valid dates.

Comment: This would mean that DateTime.Min and DateTime.Max would fail validation.